# Mysql - is composite key stored similar to a field?

Tags: mysql, composite-key

Does sql keep a record of composite keys or does it calculate them each time a record is inserted/deleted/updated...?

If it does is there a way to call it without having to get each member field value, something like ...WHERE composite_pk=CONCAT('value1','value2','value3')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, composite index is updated when field value is changed. But index has to be unique, otherwise MySql won't allow you to save a changed value. (you'll see an error:   #1062 - Duplicate entry 'a-b-c' for key 'x')

Index can't be used in WHERE statement.

useful read:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Also about index Hinting (use, ignore, force): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: Guess I cant be extra lazy. Thanks for the info.